# How to change column range incrementally as row cell is dragged down in GoogleSheets?

Tags: google-sheets, dynamic, increment, drag

I'm trying to figure out how to change the column range incrementally as the cell in column N is dragged down. I'm a little stuck.

I have managed to do this in excel using the following formula but i'm un sure how to do it in GoogleSheets?

```
=SUM(INDEX(B2:M2,ROWS(N$2:N2)+{0,1}))
```

The highlighted cells per row should equal the value in column N. The range length stays consistent but moves one to the right as the row moves down.

The value in cell `N2` should equal the `SUM(B2:C2)` and cell `N3` should equal `SUM(C3:D4)`

Any help would be greatly appreciate. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INDEX()` two times like-

```
=INDEX($B$2:$M$19,ROW(A1),ROWS($A$1:$A1))+INDEX($B$2:$M$19,ROW(A1),ROWS($A$1:$A2))
```

[image]